# How do I read this relay pinout/schematic?

Tags: relay, schematics

I'm trying to understand the way this relay works.  To me it looks like this KUHP-11DT1-12 is a DPDT relay.  Pin 7 is connected to 1 or 4 and pin 9 is connected to 3 or 6 depending on whether the coil is energized or not.

What I cannot figure out from looking at the datasheet or the diagram is which is normally open and which is normally closed.  If I had the part in hand, I could simply ohm it out, but at this point I don't yet have the device.

How can I tell from the datasheet instead of having to ohm it out?

[Product Data Sheet](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1308242_KUHP&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN)

[image: Relay Pinout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Form A relay contact is Normally Open, so since the data sheet says to delete terminals 1 and 3 for a Form A relay, those must be the Normally Closed contacts, and 4 and 6 are then the Normally Open contacts.

Comment: Pretty good deductive reasoning.  Hadn't thought of attacking the problem that way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Zoom in to the image in the datasheet. You'll see that 7 is connected to 2 on the left image, and 7 to 1 / 9 to 3 on the right image. Those are the positions when the relay is unpowered.

Comment: So when I zoom in, they do look connected.  Damn these old eyes.  Until I zoomed the image I couldn't tell they were different.  Thanks.

Comment: It's not a good image, you're eyes are not entirely to blame.